# Change permissions on Document Library

Tags: workflow, document-library, event-receivers

We want to create document libaries from previously stored templates or from new. When a library is created in a site it inherits the permissions. Is it possible to break inheritance when library is created and secondly, define new groups and permissions for the library.

UPDATE: Different permissions need to be set for libaries that contain certain content types.

Can this be achieved through a SPD workflow?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Site Workflow** which handles every list creation and do all the staff that you want to do.

Comment: Hi I've just updated the question. Which action removes the permissions on an item thats just been created?

Answer (score 0):

When you create the Library at the end of that you can break inheritance and apply the unique permission.

Check this post, it will explain how to set the item level permission, may be help you

http://maiomardesouki.com/2011/07/20/dynamic-item-permissions-from-sharepoint-designer-workflow/

Also check this powershell: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/office/To-break-the-original-8a18e0fa